# How to change atk4 PathFinder search paths priority or prepend a location from addon?

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

I want to make a jQuery-mobile addon for atk4 (version 4.3.1).

In test case I want to conditionally override the template path by prepending a location to pathfinder's 'template' locations from my addon.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Agile Toolkit default installation exposes only `/<app>/public/` folder. The ZIP file available form agiletoolkit.org actually has a copy of `vendor/atk4/atk4/public/atk4` inside `/frontend/public` and `/admin/public`.

Your best option right now is to instruct user to copy (or symlink) folder inside their "public" folder.

We are working on "activation-hook" which could be used by Add-on developers to install public assets, but it's not finalized yet.

You might also have to look into `$app->pm->public_location` and use defineContent() to conditionally list your sub-folder. This location is looked into before `$app->pm->atk_location` so will take precedence.

use `PathFinder_Location::defineContents` to list your assets.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Romans! I think for now making a full functional addon is too complex task Tempoparly resolved by overriding template in addDefaultLocations() function from separate mobile frontend.
  function addDefaultLocations() {
   $this->addLocation(array(
     'template' => 'mobile'
    ))
    ->setBasePath(getcwd()); 
  }